# How to use IIS to set request header

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Hi I have this piece of code in global.asax

```
public void Application_PreRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     .
     .
     .
     string domain = Context.HttpContext.Request.Headers[Key];
     .
     .
     .
}
```

I was told that I need to use IIS to set this header in order to test this. When this code rolls out live the header will automatically get populated by a intermediate server(not important). How do I use IIS to set the request header? The closest I've read up on is [this](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/686/setting-http-request-headers-and-iis-server-variables/). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a [setting in IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753133%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). The instructions will vary based on the version of IIS you are using.

This is based on the assumption you want to include an out going header to be consumed by another app. It allows you test a response header without redeploying your app and doing it through code.

If you want to test a request header that you can read in your code, then use something like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) or a [firefox plugin](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-headers/). This allows you to append headers when you make requests to your .NET application.

Comment: Hi I followed these steps but I cannot find the header I added in IIS within the Context.HttpContext.Request.Headers object. Could it be related to the face that I'm adding a response header in IIS but getting a request header in asp.net

Comment: That's not how it works. IIS sets the header on outbound response traffic. You will see it in fiddler, you can't access it in code.

Comment: so you are saying that if I follow the steps outlined in your link. Context.HttpContext.Request.Headers[Key] would not return any values.

Comment: It will if you pass a request header when calling the .NET page. Do this using fiddler or the Firefox plugin to modify them. It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: The link shows how to set the response header; that's different than setting a request header.

Comment: Hence the assumption and the alternative approach to setting a request header with fiddler or firefox.

Comment: The link explains to set Response Header. How to Set variables in request header?